# how to migrate filters

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, metadata-api, configuration

I have created too many filters on account object (under list view and filter catogory), wondering how to move it using change sets to another org, i tried to look for this in XML package too but could not any clue, anyone please walk me through?

[image]

Comment: Don't you see if under changeset> list views

Comment: Why not pull the list view component in change set? Filters will be package too. Just make sure you are not filtering by a Queue. [Components Available in Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=5)

Comment: no, its does not help.